# How do I merge multiple pull requests together in a local branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Imagine:

- a github project
- I have contributed there pull requests
- there are other pull requests as well from other developers
- Some of the pull requests are not yet integrated into the main branch

What I would like to do is now:

- get the main branch
- do an integration in there of multiple pull requests (my ones and from others) to get a "latest and greatest version". There is some functionality I would use now and not wait until the integration.
- Basically I want to do a integration of multiple pull requests on a local branch without write access to the original repo on github.

There are several discussions about locally syncing pull requests, but always explaining this for one single one.
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255057/how-to-fetch-someone-elses-pull-request-to-fix-it)
[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131511/how-to-update-sync-a-pull-request)

How can I integrate multiple pull requests on my local computer???

Update based on first answers and linked discussions:
Here's what I did until now:

- gqrx is the name of the project.
- integration the name of the local repository
- 1142 and 1147 are the numbers of my pull requests

```
> git clone https://github.com/gqrx-sdr/gqrx.git

> cd gqrx

> git switch -c integration master
Switched to a new branch 'integration'

> git fetch origin refs/pull/1142/head:refs/heads/1142
remote: Enumerating objects: 26, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 20), reused 20 (delta 20), pack-reused 6
Unpacking objects: 100% (26/26), 3.67 KiB | 47.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/gqrx-sdr/gqrx
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1142/head -> 1142

> git merge origin/1142
merge: origin/1142 - not something we can merge

> git merge origin/pull/1142
merge: origin/pull/1142 - not something we can merge
```

I always end up un nothing to merge, or I just have one single of the pull requests.

Comment: Create a `test-branch` from `master` branch : `git switch -c test-branch master`, then simply merge 1 by 1 the branches of said merge requests : `git fetch origin; git merge origin/feature1; git merge origin/feature2; # etc ...`

Comment: Thank you for the fast replay. I struggle with the merge command. Beside others I tried
`git merge origin/pull/1142`, `git merge origin/pull/1142` or `git merge origin/pull/1142/head:test-branch` all I get from git is `origin/pull/1142/head:integration - nichts was wir zusammenführen können` in englisch `nothing what can be merged`. What do I'm missing here?

Comment: You're missing a `git fetch` step. Note the explicit `git fetch orgiin refs/pull/<n>/head:refs/heads/pr<n>` commands in the answers to which you linked. You need one of these per PR, if you intend to do the merge and test locally in your own repository.

Comment: @Stefan: can you add what you tried and your issues to your question body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bringing all the comments above brought me to the follwing commands.

Again:

- gqrx is the name of the project.
- integration the name of the local repository
- 1142 and 1147 are the numbers of my pull requests I want to combine in one build

```
> git clone https://github.com/gqrx-sdr/gqrx.git
> cd gqrx

> git switch -c integration master

> git fetch origin pull/1142/head:refs/heads/pr1142
> git merge pr1142

> git fetch origin pull/1147/head:refs/heads/pr1147
> git merge pr1147
```

Many thanks to everybody for your support!